# How do I find research topics that yield profitable patents?

Tags: research-process, patents

How can I find (and execute) profitable, patent-producing research? Specifically, I want to produce financially rewarding patents. Are there any steps to success?

There always seems to be an element of luck, but how do I maximize chances?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Perhaps you should look at how patents are used nowadays.  In my experience, patents are used by companies as bargaining chips.  Also, do you have the $ to defend your patent if big company X infringe on your patent?  Big company X can afford to have a protracted court case, can you? Even then, can you recoup the lost?

Answer (score 2):

Pick something that has just become possible, or which people have only recently realized is possible, and which hasn't been worked to death by others.  Look for untilled soil.  If you're the first to tackle a problem, pretty nearly anything you do will be new and potentially patentable.

Comment: I used to think of it as lottery but prospective go

Answer (score 0):

One method is to do applied instead of basic science or math.  So of stem its easier in the engineering and technology/programming than in the basic science and math.